# How do I train the classifier with very large data set?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I am trying to train the model by using train_test_split(). I succeeded in that but When I try to use fit.transform() it shows error. I have a CSV file with 4521 datasets and 16 features.
This is the code I used:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x=banks.balance
y=banks.duration

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=0)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

And I keep getting an error in:

```
    ----> 9 X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
```

The error says:

```
    Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
```

and then suggests using the reshape function. I have used the rehape function as well but it does not work as the x variable becomes 4521x1.
x has the value:

```
0       1787
1       4789
2       1350
3       1476
4          0
5        747
6        307
7        147
8        221
9        -88
10      9374
11       264
12      1109
13       502
14       360
15       194
16      4073
17      2317
18      -221
19       132
20         0
21        16
22       106
23        93
24       543
25      5883
26       627
27       696
28       784
29       105
        ... 
4491       0
4492     309
4493       0
4494     668
4495    1175
4496     363
4497      38
4498    1183
4499     942
4500    4196
4501     297
4502     -91
4503     362
4504    1080
4505     620
4506    -166
4507     288
4508     642
4509    2506
4510     566
4511     668
4512    1100
4513     322
4514    1205
4515     473
4516    -333
4517   -3313
4518     295
4519    1137
4520    1136
Name: balance, Length: 4521, dtype: int64
```

and y has the following values:

```
0         79
1        220
2        185
3        199
4        226
5        141
6        341
7        151
8         57
9        313
10       273
11       113
12       328
13       261
14        89
15       189
16       239
17       114
18       250
19       148
20        96
21       140
22       109
23       125
24       169
25       182
26       247
27       119
28       149
29        74
        ... 
4491     169
4492     346
4493     205
4494     576
4495    1476
4496     171
4497     185
4498     676
4499     362
4500     193
4501      63
4502      43
4503     816
4504     951
4505    1234
4506      85
4507     306
4508     509
4509     210
4510     129
4511    1263
4512     660
4513     356
4514      45
4515     624
4516     329
4517     153
4518     151
4519     129
4520     345
Name: duration, Length: 4521, dtype: int64
```

So, Please help me out to scale the data to train the model

Comment: can you verify X_train.shape == X_test.shape

Comment: what's the problem? you set `x=banks.balance` so it seems you want X to be 1D?

Comment: Your issue is obviously not due to a "*very large data set*"; please edit & update your title accordingly since it is currently misleading

Comment: @Kenan no X_train.shape are not equal X_test.shape

Comment: @NicolasGervais I know the data is 1D. so is there a way I can use the fit.transform() without getting any error?

Comment: "_I have used the rehape function as well but it does not work as the x variable becomes 4521x1_" why won't it work?

Comment: @desertnaut I am sorry I framed the question wrong seems I can't edit due to less reputation. If you can please make it "unable to use fit_transform()"

Comment: You can *always* edit your own posts.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. x is supposed to be the features used for predictions and y is supposed to be the target. Hence, here I assigned only 1 feature to x and it is not possible to predict based only on 1 feature. I assigned 'balance' and 'duration' to x and the target with responses which was in another column response.
here is the code is used:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
feature_names= ['balance','duration']
x=banks[feature_names]
y=banks['response']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=0)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
```